# How do i use bootstrap less files in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am currently using seyhunak's bootstrap gem from [github](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) and i want to use the less versions of the bootstrap less templates at [bootswatch](http://www.bootswatch.com). simply because it would be easy for me to customise the template.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bootswatch-rails gem, already converted to sass and assets pipeline ready. But it's possible you should have to change your bootstrap gem to bootstrap-sass, but I bet it won't make any difference

https://github.com/maxim/bootswatch-rails

https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass

Comment: thanks, i have switched to bootstrap-sass and it works great! :)